# How to use python libraries stored in AWS S3 bucket as zip files in AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a ML model using AWS lambda and S3 bucket. I have very large libraries which I have compressed in zip format and placed in an S3 bucket. How can I fetch those libraries from S3 bucket and use in my code inside AWS lambda function.

Comment: you can use the ```boto3``` library [read: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html ]

Comment: boto3 is the way to go (as mentioned and up voted above). If you need another solution, you could SSH into the S3 bucket. But, I think that's a bit out of the way since you can use boto3.

Comment: I can fetch zip file from S3 using boto3 inside aws lambda function but how can I use libraries from the fetched file in AWS lambda.

Comment: @ManishKashyap once you have the library, unzip it and import it. I don't understand the question

Comment: @AdamSmith I don't know where to save the unzipped libraries in AWS lambda.

Comment: @ManishKashyap see https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/ -- "Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory." If you need more space than that you'll have to mount EFS storage.